# soap.wsdl_cache_enabled

Tags: php

I want to set value of `soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 0` in **php.ini**, but do not get any option in ini.

How to change it?

I have a WordPress plugin which gets data form a webservice, I have deleted the WSDL file but it is working, is it taking from cache?

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your config file:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your php.ini file if it is not there:

```
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0. It should disable the cache.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in you php file

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```